# Customizing the Resource in API Platform with a custom Symfony setup

Tags: symfony, react-admin, api-platform.com

I am using a custom setup of API Platform (Symfony 5 + api-pack + admin-pack). I am trying to customize the Resource List with the following

```
const entrypoint = document.getElementById('api-entrypoint').innerText;
const PropertyCreate = props => (
    <CreateGuesser {...props}>
        ...
    </CreateGuesser>
);
const PropertyEdit = props => (
    <EditGuesser {...props}>
        ...
    </EditGuesser>
);

export default () => (
    <HydraAdmin
        apiDocumentationParser={apiDocumentationParser}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        authProvider={authProvider}
        entrypoint={entrypoint}
    >
        <Resource name="properties" create={PropertyCreate} edit={PropertyEdit} />
    </HydraAdmin>
);

ReactDOM.render(<HydraAdmin entrypoint={entrypoint}/>, document.getElementById('api-platform-admin'));
```

But for some reason the Admin doesn't pick the changes. It shows the default view for Create and Edit forms.
Thank you.

Comment: The export default ... was present in the admin.js file after the install. I assumed that's the part which I have to change. But it looks like ReactDOM.render makes it totally useless. If I add the changes to ReactDOM.render then the admin doesn't get rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it is quite simple:

```
export const BookingsAdmin =
    <HydraAdmin
        apiDocumentationParser={apiDocumentationParser}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        entrypoint={entrypoint}
    >
        <Resource name="properties" create={PropertyCreate} edit={PropertyEdit}/>
        <Resource name="bookings" list={BookingsList}/>
    </HydraAdmin>;

ReactDOM.render(BookingsAdmin, document.getElementById('api-platform-admin'));
```